# HttpClient - unable to get cookie from response

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient, setcookie

In API, I use HttpClient to send request to another API. I need to use cookies in subsequent requests. Subsequent request should use the cookie set in the previous response.

But in response there is no Set-Cookie header.

Here is my code:

```
using (HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage(httpMethod, uri))
{

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonReq))
    {
        req.Content = new StringContent(jsonReq, Encoding.UTF8, APPLICATION_JSON);
    }

    req.Headers.Add(HeaderNames.Cookie, $"token={token};");
    HttpResponseMessage rsp = await proc._cli.SendAsync(req);
    string responseText = await rsp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
    if (rsp.Headers.TryGetValues("Set-Cookie", out IEnumerable<string> cookiesHeader))
    {
        foreach (string cookieHeader in cookiesHeader)
            cookies.SetCookies(proc._cli.BaseAddress, cookieHeader);
    }
    string token = cookies.GetCookies(proc._cli.BaseAddress).FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == "token")?.Value;
}
```

I tried to set up cookie on different ways, but it didn't work. When in debug there is Cookie header in the request, but no Set-Cookie header in the response.

Answer (score 0):

To use cookies in subsequent requests with `HttpClient`, you can store the received cookies from the previous response and attach them to the subsequent requests.

```cs
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main()
    {
        // Create an instance of HttpClient
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            // Make the initial request and receive the response
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://example.com/initial-request");

            // Check if the request was successful
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // Store the cookies from the response
                var cookies = response.Headers.GetValues("Set-Cookie");

                // Create a new HttpClientHandler
                HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
                
                // Attach the received cookies to the handler
                handler.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                foreach (var cookie in cookies)
                {
                    handler.CookieContainer.SetCookies(new Uri("https://example.com"), cookie);
                }

                // Use the handler with a new instance of HttpClient
                using (HttpClient subsequentClient = new HttpClient(handler))
                {
                    // Make subsequent requests with the cookies attached
                    HttpResponseMessage subsequentResponse = await subsequentClient.GetAsync("https://example.com/subsequent-request");

                    // Process the subsequent response as needed
                    if (subsequentResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        // Handle the response
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Handle the error
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Handle the error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The initial request is made using the original `HttpClient` instance. The response headers are inspected to retrieve the cookies, which are then attached to a new `HttpClientHandler`. Finally, subsequent requests are made using a new `HttpClient` instance with the updated handler, ensuring that the cookies are included in each subsequent request.

Note that the code assumes the API you're interacting with uses cookies for session management. Additionally, you may need to modify the code to fit your specific API and requirements.

Comment: Hello! thanks for help. This approach did not help, it is the same. When I try in Postman, it returns cookie, but in code not